Will LISA be able to detect quantum corrections to the waveforms of gravitational radiation?
My main motivation for asking this question is this paper, in which the authors calculate the periodic orbits of a
small celestial object around a supermassive quantum-corrected black hole and the corresponding gravitational waveforms. Loop quantum gravity is used to calculate a correction to the Schwarzschild metric:
$$ds^2=-\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{\alpha M^2}{r^4} \right)dt^2+\left(1-\frac{2M}{r}+\frac{\alpha M^2}{r^4} \right)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\theta^2+r^2sin^2\theta d\phi^2 $$
Here geometrized units ($G=c=1$) are used and the quantum correction parameter is $\alpha=16\sqrt{3}\pi\gamma^3l_P^2$, where $\gamma$ is the Immirzi parameter. The authors also define the dimensionless quantity $\widehat{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha}{M^2}$. The paper then goes on to demonstrate that the characteristic strain of the gravitational waveforms for $\widehat{\alpha}=0$, $\widehat{\alpha}=0.8$ and $\widehat{\alpha}=1.6$ exceeds LISA's sensitivity curve in the mHz range, which means LISA may be able to distinguish between them.
I am confused about the numerical value of $\widehat{\alpha}$. On the one hand, the paper claims:

Note that, in fact, the value of the parameter $\widehat{\alpha}$ should be very small. However,
we are qualitatively studying the impact of the parameter $\widehat{\alpha}$ on periodic orbits and their gravitational waves in this
work. Therefore, we choose relatively large values for the parameter $\widehat{\alpha}$.

This suggests that $\widehat{\alpha}$ was chosen to be unrealistically large in order to more clearly visualize the different gravitational waveforms. On the other hand, the paper concludes with:

We found
that parts of the characteristic strains, with different $(w, v, z)$ or with different values of the parameter $\widehat{\alpha}$, exceed the
sensitivity curve of LISA. This implies that future space-based gravitational wave detectors may detect gravitational
waves emitted from EMRIs with periodic orbits, and we may potentially utilize such gravitational wave signals to
investigate the quantum gravitational properties of supermassive black holes.

In this case, the authors appear to claim that LISA may be able to detect the quantum corrections. This seems improbable to me. The Planck length $l_P$ is roughly $10^{-35}$meters and the solar mass in geometrized coordinates is around $10^3$ meters. Given that the mass of a supermassive black hole is many, many solar masses, we get:
$$\widehat{\alpha}=\frac{\alpha}{M^2}=\frac{16\sqrt{3}\pi\gamma^3l_P^2}{M^2}\ll \left(\frac{10^{-35}m}{10^3m}\right)^2=10^{-74}$$
This should be practically indistinguishable from the case $\widehat{\alpha}=0$. It feels as if I'm either misinterpreting the conclusions of the paper, or making a really stupid mistake somewhere.
Hence the question: will quantum corrections due to loop quantum gravity potentially be detectable by LISA or other upcoming gravitational wave detectors? Additionally, do the predictions of LQG in this scenario differ measurably from those of other theories of quantum gravity such as string theory, entropic gravity or linearized quantum gravity?

The way I understand the paper, they are essentially saying that for large enough $\alpha$, the waveforms are changed enough that LISA can measure the deviations. So, LISA can put upper bounds on the $\alpha$ parameter. Now, it may be that these upper bounds are not interesting theoretically (since on theoretical grounds it looks like the expected value of $\alpha$ is 74 orders of magnitude or so below the upper limits they can achieve), but calculating what would happen if $\alpha$ were that big and comparing to LISA's sensitivity is a legitimate scientific exercise.

As a caveat, I'm not an expert on LQG, so I'm not confident enough in what they are saying to make this an answer. But, I'll just say from experience working in gravitational wave data analysis, that there are a lot of papers like this one that propose an effect that is so large that we don't expect to see it theoretically, but which we can bound experimentally. This can be valuable since it gives you a measure of "how close" current observations are to interesting theoretical models, and proves that at least in principle observations can bound non-GR theories.

Thanks for your comments. So based on this paper I would expect the answer to my question to be 'no'. Do you know of any literature about gravitational waves as a test for more 'realistic' models of quantum gravity?
